# How to run Photoshop 2020 with standard "screen sizing"?

Tags: windows

I'm using Windows 10 with 150% increase size as set in this configuration

Anyway , I want to run Photoshop 2020 with 'standard' size window .. How to do ?

[image]

Comment: Windows supports applying those settings per application.  That option is within the "advanced scaling settings"

Comment: It not works.. i tried all possibility but Photoshop run scaled up so I can't work on it !